# Alternative colloquialism for "Best of both worlds"?

Tags: phrase-requests, colloquialisms

I'm looking for a phrase that means the same thing as "best of both worlds", except isn't so overused.

I'm looking for the semantics to remain intact; for example, "Awesome!!" would not be an acceptable substitute. I'm describing a thing, which I claim will solve two discrete problems. I'd like to be able to say something like "Not only does this solve X, but it also solves Y. It truly is *the best of both worlds*"

Comment: Unless X and Y are two long-standing problems where attempts to solve one would normally make the other one *worse*, I don't think OP's usage would apply anyway. His solution may be *Adaptable, Resourceful, All-round, All-purpose, Many- sided, Multi-purpose, Multifaceted, Flexible*, for example, but it probably doesn't combine the best features of two things that are normally thought of as incompatible.

Comment: I'd go with *double whammy*. But then, I'm not in the business of selling anything to anyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An obvious one which occurs to me is a *[win-win game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win-win_game)* or *win-win situation*, both of which indicate a *[non-zero-sum game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-zero-sum_game)*. The term *non-zero-sum game* can apply to situations where both sides win or both sides lose, but is typically taken to be positive. For instance:

> "I'm not paying you unless you deliver on time." 
> "You know, with your help, we could deliver on time and make it even better too. It's not a zero-sum game."

Answer (score 7):

To [kill two birds with one stone](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kill_two_birds_with_one_stone) is to solve two problems at once.

You might also consider saying that the solution does both things [in one fell swoop](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one_fell_swoop) (at one time or with one action), though this is not limited to accomplishing only two things.

Keep in mind that to be [the best of both worlds](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/best_of_both_worlds) typically connotes not necessarily solving two problems, but combining two things that normally don't go together. Consider [examples](http://books.google.com/books?id=axeaKDxAVZkC&lpg=PA292&dq=%22it%27s%20the%20best%20of%20both%20worlds%22&pg=PA292#v=onepage&q=%22it%27s%20the%20best%20of%20both%20worlds%22&f=false) like, "it's the best of both worlds because we have the feel of a small college but the resources of a large university". In such cases, it's often a stretch to imagine how something can really have both of these benefits (is it truly [a floor wax and a dessert topping](http://snltranscripts.jt.org/75/75ishimmer.phtml)?) which probably contributes to your feeling that the idiom is cliché.

If your desire is to avoid the overused, you might choose a simple variant of your original language, perhaps emphasizing that both problems are solved at once: *Not only does this solve X, but it simultaneously solves Y.*

Answer (score 4):

One can also **have their cake and eat it too**.

Comment: Actually, **one** can't have **their** cake. One can only have one's cake!

Comment: But what if one wants one's cake and theirs too?

Comment: This is actually a corrupted version of "eat your cake and have it too" (because you can't usually have cake once you've eaten it, of course. You *can*, though, eat cake once you have it :)

Answer (score 2):

The term ***two-for-one*** (also ***[twofer](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/twofer)***) can apply here. I don't think of it as a synonym for the phrase *best of both worlds*, but it does work perfectly to illustrate *a thing that solves two discrete problems*.

> 1. a cheap item of merchandise; *especially*: a cigar selling at two for
>      a nickel
> 2. a free coupon entitling the bearer to purchase two
>      tickets to a specified theatrical production for the price of one
> 3. two articles available for the price of one or about the price of one
> 4. **something that satisfies two criteria or needs simultaneously**

Answer (score 0):

A "double play" (a term from baseball).