# Having the best of both worlds (i.e. methods)

Tags: phrase-requests

I want a phrase for the main title of my academic poster for a general audience.

**Context:** "In microbiology, our proposed [method Z] combines the [advantages] of [established methods X and Y]."

Some ideas from [Alternative colloquialism for "Best of both worlds"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43877/alternative-colloquialism-for-best-of-both-worlds) are:

"best of both worlds" - I don't want any allusions to Hannah Montana

"kill two birds with one stone" - not good for this context, sounds too violent

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should just say:

> "In microbiology, our proposed [method Z] combines the ***best*** of
>   [established methods X and Y]."

Ando so, (based on all those titles of academic papers that I have seen) the title that automatically springs to my mind is:

> A proposed method to combine the best of [method x] and [method y]

Maybe it can be made a bit informal as:

> Combining Best of [Method x] and [Method y]

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking for a *poster title* with a similar meaning to "having the best of both worlds"

Comment: Thanks for alerting me that you are looking for a *title*. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> Having your cake and eating it

Springs to mind.

or more fitting for a title perhaps?..

> Having the Microbial cake and eating it.

Edit: [Reference](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-your-cake-and-eat-it-too)